# Regex match everything before the pattern at the end of the string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to build a regex that would include everything *before* a certain pattern at the end of the string.

This is my starting pattern:

```
/\.\w{2,3}(\.\w{2,3})?$/g
```

If I give it a string such as `db.google.com` or `google.co.uk` or `test.db.google.co.uk`, it selects the ending like `.co.uk` or `.com`.

I want to reverse it so that it selects only what comes beforehand. So it should match these strings:

- `db.google.com` ⇒ `db.google`
- `google.co.uk` ⇒ `google`
- `test.db.google.co.uk` ⇒ `test.db.google`

Could someone please help?

Comment: What language/tool are you running the regex in? There are different solutions which will work in some regex "flavours" but not others.

Comment: Powershell Script

Comment: `[\w.]+?(?=(\.\w{2,3}){1,2}$)` might work for you. Test it well on your data, in particular you shouldn't expect every TLD to be 2-3 chars wide (e.g. `.info`)

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron I am kind of new to regular patterns could not figure it out myself. I will definitely test it. It is required for my local development. I set up IIS hosts based on the folder name so if there is a fault my script won't work but won't cause serious damage. Just automatization

Comment: I got to `'google.co.uk' -match '^(.*?)(?=(\.\w{2,3}\.\w{2,3}|\.\w{2,3})$)'` as the only way I could get it to match both endings if there were two, my attempts at `{1,2}` just didn't seem to force it the way I wanted.

Comment: Aarons solution did not work in powershell

Comment: I don't know the first thing about powershell, but it seems to work for me? ([TIO link](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Xz09Pz89J1UvOV@vNFtdQTc3sSQ5Q0E9OqZcL1bbXsPeViNGL6a82kjHuFaz2lDHqFZFU50LoSmXWC3Y9cRp6GnZa2LX8v8/AA) )

Comment: Anyway the point is to take your whole current pattern (`\.\w{2,3}(\.\w{2,3})?$`) and put it inside a lookahead (`(?=\.\w{2,3}(\.\w{2,3})?$)`) that follows a lazy wildcard (`.*?(?=\.\w{2,3}(\.\w{2,3})?$)`)

Comment: @Aaron yep that does work

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. That is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call me dense but I think you are over thinking it. If you want to select the opposite of your current regex why not just use it in a replace? Something like this:

```
$re = '\.\w{2,3}(\.\w{2,3})?$'
'db.google.com' -replace $re #=> db.google
'google.co.uk' -replace $re #=> google
'test.db.google.co.uk' -replace $re #=> test.db.google
```

Comment: Well, that's my lack of knowledge in PowerShell which prevents me to come out with these this kind of solutions. That is definitely an easier option.